# $_POST Array is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with XAMPP and PHPStorm v9, running locally, a simple application that does an AJAX callback.

My server handler for the AJAX request is showing an empty $_POST array and I have no idea why. Before I take all of this code and run on a different server, to eliminate the platform as the issue, does anyone see why the $_POST array would be empty? Any suggestions? Thanks

The XHR pane, shows the post executed.
[image]

**The JS**

```
if (valid) {

    var queryStr = 'fName=' + firstName.val() + '&lName=' + lastName.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val();

    var f = firstName.val();
    var l = lastName.val();
    var e = email.val();
    var p = phone.val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ACS567-Projects/addContact.php',
        data: {
            fName: f,
            lName: l,
            email: e,
            phone: p
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: OnAddSuccess,
        error: OnAddFailure,
        timeout: 60000
    });
}
```

**The PHP handler**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['fName'])) {

    $firstName = $_POST['fName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $addressBook->addContact($firstName,$lastName,$email,$phone);

    echo "<b>success</b>";
    exit();
}

echo "<b>failure</b>";
exit();
```

Comment: Try setting `processData` to `false` and/or do a `var_dump` on the `$_POST` array to see what you are getting instead. Your data is probably converted into a query string before sending.

Comment: how you know so POST is empty? Open your browser web tools and check network XHR what you're sending

Comment: I logged the $_POST check from inside the handler and POST is empty:foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $str.=$key." =>".$val;

}

Comment: @Slinky handler? from script what you posted ... how you can be sure the POST data is populated and exist in method addContact? .. pls what you are got from response? succes or failure html? If you don't see any of both you have problem upper.

Comment: hmm your POST is empty because you don't send nothing :D ... is if (valid) { really VALID ?

Comment: Yes, the data is valid and the PHP handler is getting called but $_POST is empty. The AJAX response is the "failure" message as well

Comment: Is request being made to different localhost port than page is on? use arguments in error handler to trace down issues

Answer (score 0):

Data will not automatically turn into an array ready for use in your PHP script. Read the jQuery documentation:

> It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Also, you should use 'method' instead of 'type' if you don't have an old jQuery version.

More info on the .ajax function found here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Have you inspected your client/browser to see what is posted and dumped the $_POST variable to see that it's really empty?